# Wordpress Database Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Wordpress gives me the following error when trying to repair my database.

Why is is looking for tables that have that *1* in them? The ones in my database do not?

I am making multisite.

```
wp_1_posts: Table 'school.wp_1_posts' doesn't exist
wp_1_comments: Table 'school.wp_1_comments' doesn't exist
wp_1_links: Table 'school.wp_1_links' doesn't exist
wp_1_options: Table 'school.wp_1_options' doesn't exist
wp_1_postmeta: Table 'school.wp_1_postmeta' doesn't exist
wp_1_terms: Table 'school.wp_1_terms' doesn't exist
wp_1_term_taxonomy: Table 'school.wp_1_term_taxonomy' doesn't exist
wp_1_term_relationships: Table 'school.wp_1_term_relationships' doesn't exist
wp_1_commentmeta: Table 'school.wp_1_commentmeta' doesn't exist
```

Comment: it seems that you have the wrong database prefix, check the `wp-config.php` file

Comment: No, /**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

Answer (score 2):

I hade the same problem today. I activated multisite with adding

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true )
```

Then folllowed the steps to replace .htaccess and add the following lines to wp-config.php.

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

I accidentally missed the first line! I added it and that solved the problem.
wp-config.php needs to contain both lines:

```
 define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true )
```

and

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
```

I found the solution here at the bottom: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_1_-tables-not-created-in-new-multisite-install

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Network Sites by any chance?  The numeric component to the prefix usually represents a blog ID for WP installations containing more than one site (meaning you've perhaps activated [the multisite option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#Step_2:_Allow_Multisite) in wp-config.php).

Comment: Yes I am trying to activate a multisite, but it told me that my database was broken, so I tried this to fix it. Where now?